# Screen doesnt re-render even props changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, state

I'm currently facing a problem where the screen doesnt re-render to load the new added value to array. Even tried with componentWillReceiveProps and trigger a `this.forceUpdate()` manually doesn't help. The screen only show the new value when I restart the app

```
this.props.addNewRecord({ 
    recordDetails: { ...this.props.recordDetails, type: this.state.type },
    records: this.props.records
  });

return (
  <View>
    {
      this.props.records.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text>{`${i}: `}</Text>
            <Text>{x.id}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })
    }
  </View>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ account, settings, main }) => {
  const year = moment().year();
  const month = moment().format('MMM');

  return {
    records: account.records[year][month].records,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SummaryScreen);
```

account.records has the following structure

```
{
  2018: {
    Jan: {
      records: [{...}, {...}]
    }
  }
}
```

And below is the adding record part

```
const addNewRecord = ({ recordDetails, records }) => {
  const year = moment(recordDetails.date).year();
  const month = moment(recordDetails.date).format('MMM');

  const newRec = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    account_id: recordDetails.account_id,
    date: recordDetails.date,
    description: recordDetails.description,
    amount: recordDetails.result,
    type: recordDetails.type
  };

  update(year, month, newRec, records);

  return {
    type: ADD_NEW_RECORD,
    payload: records
  };
};

const update = (year, month, obj, target) => {
  [year, month].reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    if (!a[i + 1] && r[e]) {
      r[e].records.push(obj);

      if (obj.type === 'expense') r[e].totalExpenses = parseFloat(r[e].totalExpenses) + parseFloat(obj.amount);
      if (obj.type === 'income') r[e].totalIncome = parseFloat(r[e].totalIncome) + parseFloat(obj.amount);
    }
    return r[e] = (r[e] || (a[i + 1] ? {} : {
      records: [obj],
      totalExpenses: obj.type === 'expense' ? parseFloat(obj.amount) : 0,
      totalIncome: obj.type === 'income' ? parseFloat(obj.amount) : 0,
      type: obj.type
    }));
  }, target);
};
```

And Reducer as below:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_NEW_RECORD:
    return { ...state, records: action.payload };
```

Comment: Are you using Redux with Thunk middleware?

Comment: @Ziyo, Nope I'm not

Comment: Can I see how your addNewRecord gets triggered

Comment: @Ziyo: It's a button onPress event calling `this.props.addNewRecord`. I've included in first section of code

Comment: Your code looks fine though. Are you using local state?

Comment: @Ziyo: Only `this.state.type` which to pass along into `this.props.addNewRecord`. Yeah I can't see how I violate any of the rules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181450/discussion-between-ziyo-and-isaac).

Comment: Are you extending React.Component or React.PureComponent?

Comment: @Y.Gherbi: React.Component

Comment: You could try using something like react native devtools to  check is the props in your component are changing. If you want to push it to git I could take a look at it!

Comment: @Y.Gherbi: I did utilize `Reactotron` and I do see the props changed. Logically speaking, the props has to be changed, because when I restart the app, the records showing correctly

Comment: Hmm okay. Btw, where are you savind to data to any kind of database? Could you please include that part ?

Comment: @Y.Gherbi: I'm using `https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline`

Comment: Aaaaa I see! You are passing this.props.records to addNewRecord and here you are modifying the abject which prevents react refux from rerenderen. Try deepcloning it or making a completely new object. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/585#issuecomment-132865158

Comment: @Y.Gherbi: It make sense! Let me have a try and share the result asap thanks!

Comment: @Y.Gherbi: Yes it works perfectly now many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.props.addNewRecord({ 
  recordDetails: { ...this.props.recordDetails, type: this.state.type },
  records: _.cloneDeep(this.props.records)//this.props.records
});
```

The problem is I've passed `this.props.records` as `records` which later gets mutated, and eventually old state get mutated to be the same as new state and that's why Redux unable to spot the differences.

Credits to @Y.Gherbi for spotted this flaw. Hope it helps whoever facing same issue